# Возможно ли решить проблему с разделителями в csv?

Tags: php, csv

написал простенький php-скрипт (даже скажем скопировал с сайта) который выгружает данный с БД в csv-файл. Скрипт работает, но как я полагаю, специфика данных в БД искажает их добавление по столбцам, то-есть у мня есть например 2 столбца - 1. Наименование товара, 2. Описание товара. В этих столбцах присутствуют коммы, точки с запятой и знаки табуляции. Получается, что во время формирования csv-файла, один из таких знаков расценивается как разделитель, в таком случаи одно описание товара может разорвать на три или четыре столбца, тем самым сместив другие данные. В таблице около 15к товаров и 9 столбцов. Собственно вопрос - можно ли сделать так, дабы ничего не рвало - одна ячейка в БД === одна ячейка в csv-файле. Ниже прилагаю сам скрипт, и снимок экрана, где видно как хорошо ложатся данные когда из запроса убрал два проблемных ряда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php
/**
* Описание: экспорт данных из таблицы MySQL в .CSV-файл
*/

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "sofishop_product");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Определение формата файла
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');

// Имя файла
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export-from-db.csv');

// создать поток вывода файла
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// вывод заголовков столбцов
/*
fputcsv($output, array('post_title', 'sku', 'stock', 'post_content', 'width', 'height', 'length', 'regular_price', 'images'), ';');
$query = "SELECT title,companycode,stock_quantity,description,width,height,length,price,picture FROM product";*/

fputcsv($output, array('sku', 'stock', 'width', 'height', 'length', 'regular_price', 'images'), ';');
$query = "SELECT companycode,stock_quantity,width,height,length,price,picture FROM product";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

// цикл по строкам, вывод их
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) :

fputcsv($output, $line, ';');

endwhile;

mysqli_free_result($results);

fclose($output);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: На вики есть примеры csv https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values. В конце страницы пример с разделителем в качестве запятой и в тексте есть запятая. Пример: `1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00`

Comment: Хорошо что такой пример есть, но у меня так не работает((( никто не подскажет что с етим можно сделать?

Comment: Не работаю с php, но к примеру в python есть специальный модуль csv, который можно настраивать: разделитель, двойные кавычки и т.п. Попробуйте поискать подобный для php. Первый результат в гугле: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php см. ф-ию fputcsv()